# How to pass multiple values through command line arguments in void function?

Tags: c, pthreads, command-line-arguments

```
#define SMALL_STACK 131072 //128K for stack
pthread_attr_t thread_attr; //for attr

void* fn(void* arg)
{ //fn fuction
  printf("%d", (char *) arg);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Have ");
  printf(" arguments:"); //checking multiple arguments
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&thread_attr, SMALL_STACK);
  pthread_t th; //creating thread and stack

  /* I Need Help (void*)&argv[1] passing this to void *fn function printing the argument coming from command line arguments */

  pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, (void*) &argv[1]); //creating thread

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should pass a `struct` instance to your thread parameter.

Below, an example:

```
struct MyThreadData
{
    int argc,
    char** argv;
}

void* fn(void* arg)
{
    MyThreadData* data=(MyThreadData*)arg;
    /*code*/
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*...*/
    MyThreadData td={0};
    td.argc=argc;
    td.argv=argv;

    void* ret = NULL;
    pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, (void*)&td);
    pthread_join(th,&ret)
}
```

Comment: Both casts (`(void*)` and `(MyThreadData*)`) aren't necessary in C.

Comment: Totally agree, I explicitely let these casts to enforce the concept understanding.

Comment: Which concept? The only concept here is that in C a `void`-pointer implicitly converts to and from any other pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To pass **one** argument (here: the 1st) change

```
pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, (void*)&argv[1]);
```

to be

```
pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, argv[1]);
```

To inside the thread function print the string use the *correct* conversion specifier:

```
printf("%s", (char *)arg);
```

or in a "cleaner" manner do

```
void* fn(void* arg)
{
  char * pc = arg;
  printf("%s\n", pc); /* add a new-line to flush stdout, to 
                         have this printed immediately. */
```

To pass **all** arguments then change

```
pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, (void*)&argv[1]);
```

to be

```
pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, argv);
```

and adjust the thread function as follows:

```
void* fn(void* arg)
{
  char ** ppc = arg;

  while (*ppc)
  {
    printf("%s\n", *ppc);
    ++ppc;
  }

  ...
```

---

Also make sure `main()` does not return the standard way, as this then ends the process, which in turn ends all threads of the process.

To do so replace

```
return 0;
```

by

```
pthread_exit(NULL);
```